# How to multiply array of ones by random numbers

Tags: python, arrays, random

I am trying to multiply each value in my array of ones by a random number. Each time I try by a method of iteration, I get an error saying: 'IndexError: index out of bounds.'
Here is my code:

```
from physics import *
N = 3.0
x = ones(N)

for i in x:
    x[i] = i * uniform(10)
```

Numpy is stored in the physics import.

I've done it this way so that when I come back I can easily change the number of ones in my array by changing my value of `N`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you have to use the `physics` library, use this code:

```
>>> import random
>>> array = [1]*random.randint(1, 10)
>>> array
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
>>> for i, j in enumerate(array):
...     array[i] = j*random.randint(1, 10)
... 
>>> array
[3, 7, 5, 1, 2]
>>>
```

Your code isn't working because you are doing `for i in x`, which is assigning `i` to every value of `x`. Instead, change the `for i in x` to `for i in range(0, len(x))` or `for i in range(len(x))`.

Comment: My aim is to basically produce an array of N terms each with a random number. When I use the len(x) function it turns my array back into a normal range. 
I want to avoid using random to directly produce this array as i would have less control over the random number produced

Answer (score 0):

`i` in `for-loop` is always 1. to treat `i` as index of `x`, it should be replaced with `range(len(x))` which generates `[0, 1, ... N-1]`

```
from physics import *
N = 3.0
x = ones(N)

for i in range(len(x)):
    x[i]=i*uniform(10)
```

Also, you can rewrite as

```
import numpy as np
x = np.random.uniform(0, 10, N) * np.arnage(N)
```

where `0` is low, `10` is high, and `N` is size.

Comment: When I change it to range(len(x)) it makes my original array turn into array(0, 1, 2) when I still want it to remain as ones.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have the length in a variable, it's just

```
N = 10    
x = numpy.ones(N)
x *= numpy.random.uniform(10, size=N)
```