# RGB imaging via using np.newaxis, expanding from (:,:,1) to (:,:,3)

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing

I am trying to take what is originally a list "ThetaVect1" which is turned in to an np.ndarray which has a shape of (16,), changing it to a (4,4) array and then using np.newaxis to get a third dimension which I am trying to set to be 3, but can not figure out how.

The thought is, that once I do that I can add coloring to my greyscale images based on random numbers np.random.randint(0,255) that vary for each "pixel". So while I can get print(Greyscale_Theta1_RGB.shape) = (4,4,1) I can not get it in to the (4,4,3) format. I believe this is what needs to be done.

I am trying to work via the following idea [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48571486/converting-from-numpy-arrays-to-a-rgb-image)

```
Greyscale_ThetaVect1 = np.array(ThetaVect1,dtype=np.uint8)
print(Greyscale_ThetaVect1.shape)
Greyscale_Theta1 = np.reshape(Greyscale_ThetaVect1, (-1, 4))

Greyscale_Theta1_RGB = Greyscale_Theta1[:,:,None]
# Greyscale_Theta1_RGB [:,:,0] = np.random.randint(0,255)
# Greyscale_Theta1_RGB [:,:,1] = np.random.randint(0,255)
# Greyscale_Theta1_RGB [:,:,2] = np.random.randint(0,255)

print(Greyscale_Theta1_RGB.shape)

save_file = "CM.jpg"
i = Image.fromarray(Greyscale_Theta1).save(save_file)

i = Image.open("CM.jpg")
i.show()
```

### EDIT

Using Mark Setchell's great answer together with the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23097068/how-to-multiply-array-of-ones-by-random-numbers) I am trying to put random colors in the 2-D image array. I got something using this code:

```
for k,l in enumerate(rgb):
    print(l)
    rgb[k] = l * [random.randint(0, 255),random.randint(0, 255),random.randint(0, 255)]
```

It is not quite correct as there are evident black lines as well as a black strip at the beginning.  The image is enlarged to show the straight black lines.

[image]

I also removed the gradient by changing f to : `f = lambda i, j: int((128))` and was able to get this interesting image, though notice that there are not pixels but lines instead.

[image]

Comment: `newaxis` like `reshape` does not add elements to the array; so you can make a (n,m,1) array.  A (n,m,3) array will be 3x as big.  You could start with `arr[:,:,np.newaxis).repeat(3,2)`, which replicates the array along that new 3rd axis.  The initial 4x4 shape is small enough that you can experiment and display the whole array.

Comment: Your way of setting randint values will produce a uniformly colored image, without any information left from the original.  All pixels will have the same color and intensity.  You could just as well start with a `np.zeros((4,4,3), 'uint8')` array.

Comment: Thanks hpaulj. Perhaps I should start with a np.zeros((4,4,3), 'unit8') image and try to insert the reshaped Greyscale_Theta1 image? I couldn't figure out how to do this either and my post seemed the closest solution.

Comment: I'm totally baffled as to what you want to do. You start with a greyscale 4x4 image and end up with a randomly coloured 700x300 image. Why not just make a randomly coloured 700x300 image in the first place? What's the 4x4 greyscale image got to do with the result?

Answer (score 2):

Just putting flesh on comment from @hpaulj ...

Simply copy and append the pieces of code below in order without the images interspersed to get a single, runnable lump of code.

I think you have a greyscale image that you want to annotate in colour but can't work out how to make it into an RGB image and also, presumably, preserve the grey values you already have.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# Define width and height big enough to see
w,h = 256,100

# Make left-right gradient of greyscale values - without going to pure white so you can see the extent on StackOverflow's white background
f = lambda i, j: int((j*192)/w)
gg = np.fromfunction(np.vectorize(f), (h,w)).astype(np.uint8)
```

That gives us this single channel greyscale image:

[image]

```
# Replicate greyscale and stack to make RGB image where R=G=B
rgb = gg[:,:,np.newaxis].repeat(3,2)

# If you find the above syntax difficult, here is an alternative
# ... stack the grey image 3 times in the "depth" dimension
# rgb = np.dstack((gg,gg,gg))

# DEBUG: Save image
Image.fromarray(rgb).save('result1.png')
```

That gives us this RGB image:

[image]

```
# DRAWING PART
# Make top edge red 10px wide
rgb[:10,:,:]=[255,0,0]

# Make left border green 20px wide
rgb[:,:20,:]=[0,255,0]

# Make right border blue 30px wide
rgb[:,:-30:-1,:]=[0,0,255]

# DEBUG: Save image
Image.fromarray(rgb).save('result2.png')
```

[image]

If you want to draw or colour the image using PIL rather than using Numpy, remove the code following "DRAWING PART" above and replace with the following:

```
from PIL import ImageDraw 

# Make PIL Image from numpy array
rgb = Image.fromarray(rgb)

# Get drawing handle and draw magenta circle and save
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(rgb)
draw.ellipse([10,10,90,90],fill=(255,0,255))
rgb.save('result.png')
```

[image]

---

If you just want a 700x300 random image:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# Generate a random image 700x300 
im = np.random.randint(0,256,(300,700,3), dtype=np.uint8)                                  

# Make into PIL Image, display and save
p = Image.fromarray(im)
p.display()
p.save('result.png')
```

[image]

If you wanted to make the random image atop a gradient, you could do this:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# Generate a random image 700x300 
im = np.random.randint(0,256,(300,700,3), dtype=np.uint8) 

gradient = np.linspace(0,1,700,dtype=np.float32) + np.zeros(300)[:, None] 
im = im*np.dstack((gradient,gradient,gradient))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks a bunch for your awesome examples! With your help and another stack exchange question I was able to get some colors, though I see that it is not exactly correct (see Edit in my original post), I am getting lines of colors vs. pixels of various colors. Let me know if you have any thoughts. Thanks though again.

Comment: Thanks for that. How then would one pixelwise multiply the rgb image you generated above with this random one so as to create a new image - so that you could do something say such as a gradient/random hybrid. So that, concerning the gradient rgb image, it would be darker random colors on the left progressing towards the full spectrum of random numbers on the right of the image?

Comment: Also, in the random color image you put in the edit, it has a pattern of small connected boxes, that is cool, how did you do that?

Comment: Hi Mark, I can't seem to reproduce what you have. I get the error "TypeError: Cannot handle this data type". Now if I change the datatype from float32 to uint8 and remove the part:  np.zeros(300)[:, None]   then I do get a black 700,300 rectangle.   The error comes because of the line: p = Image.fromarray(im). Any ideas why? Thanks.

Comment: I also had found previously that for the random color image that I would get an error at the line p.display() which said "'Image' object has no attribute 'display'". I fixed this by using p.show() which gave the random color pixel image. Why does this work for you and not me? Thanks.